# How do I do this? Please help me!

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How do I do this? Please help me!

Comment: Welcome! You can use `tikz` and `tikzmark` to draw that. This is all very easy, except you may have to wait a while till you find someone who punches in the texts from the screen shot for you.

Comment: It looks as the martyrdom of Saint Sebastian. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - Yeah, all those arrows do look rather menacing, don't they?! Poor formula: it's not going to survive this onslaught for long...

Comment: Some inspiration regarding the arrows: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522517/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522441/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281121/134144

Comment: please edit the title to be useful for searching later, the site does not want 200000 questions all called "please help"  also add a small complete test document so people offering to help can see what you tried and explain what is wrong, and do not have to type in all that text themselves.

Comment: i just made this same thing  a day ago -- why this kolaveri di--

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to annotate equations (i.e. arrow signs/curly braces) to define each variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522441/is-it-possible-to-annotate-equations-i-e-arrow-signs-curly-braces-to-define-e)

Answer (score 1):

The formulae will have to be punched in by the OP

Something to get started in the right direction --adapted from

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/global-nodes/

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% For every picture that defines or uses external nodes, you'll have to
% apply the 'remember picture' style. To avoid some typing, we'll apply
% the style to all pictures

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

% By default all math in TikZ nodes are set in inline mode. Change this to
% displaystyle so that we don't get small fractions

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Physical Experiment Response
        \tikz\node [fill=blue!20,draw,circle] (n1) {};
\end{itemize}

% Below we mix an ordinary equation with TikZ nodes. Note that we have to
% adjust the baseline of the nodes to get proper alignment with the rest of
% the equation

\begin{equation}
            \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)
            {$y^e(x)$};
        } 
        =
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base] (t2)
            {$y^m(x,\theta^*)$};
        } 
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Computer Model Response
        \tikz\node [fill=red!20,draw,circle] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}

% Now it's time to draw some edges between the global nodes. Note that we
% have to apply the 'overlay' style

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->] (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);
        \path[->] (n2) edge [bend right] (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is unsupported, use `\tikzset` instead.